# Why my Cross-Platform projects in Visual Studio are different from all the online tutorials?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a cross-platform project to build an app to be running on Microsoft Surface, and I m new to this area.

I googled some tutorials online and they all say that you go to new project, select Cross-Platform, you will see Cross Platform app (Xamarin), Class Library (Xamarin.Forms) and so on.

But when I select Cross-Platform, I only see ONE option: Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms). Is it the new feature or am I missing some components in VS.

If it is a new feature, is there any tutorial regarding how to create an windows surface app using it?

Probably this is an easy question but a million thanks to you!

Comment: Microsoft updates the templates with each VS2017 update, so they change very often. Pick the one offered

Comment: even though this topic is put on hold as off-topic, I still thank Saladin and magicandre1981 for giving me the instructions, and I now find the right documents!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft works constantly on Xamarin, so templates for cross-platform projects may change every time you update your Visual Studio.

- Try to check the date of your tutorial
- Choose recent tutorials
- Watch videos on Xamarin youtube channel

Use the Microsoft documentation website for recent tutorials : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/

Comment: Blog posts on recent changes: [.NET Standard Comes to Xamarin.Forms Project Templates!](https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-comes-xamarin-forms-project-templates/) and [New Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS Project Templates Now Available](https://blog.xamarin.com/new-xamarin-android-ios-templates/).  The second one doesn't directly address cross-platform, but it discusses some general motivations for template and wizard changes.